# Custom Data Types

Tags: c#, .net, enums, types

I'd like to create some custom data types, but I don't think I'm asking the right question(s).

There are "compound Boolean" values used throughout .NET, and I want to design some of my own.
I've been using a series of Boolean variables, which works, but just isn't the same.

Examples from .NET include:
Color.Black
Alignment.Centered
[fontProperties].Bold*
*I forget the actual name, but you get the idea

I want to make something like this:

**ColorSortQualities**

- None
- DistinguishColor
- DistinguishNumberOfColors
- DistinguishColorPattern

Once that's been declared, I could do this:
if(searchOptions.ColorSortQualities == DistinguishColor)
[do stuff]

What is this called?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to have both 'DistinguishColor' and 'DistinguishColorPattern' at the same time, or are they mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called an enumeration and in C# you use the keyword [`enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Use an enum:

```
  enum ColorSortQualities
  {
       None,
       DistinguishColor,
       DistinguishNumberOfColors,
       DistinguishColorPattern
  };
```

Comment: unecessarily explicitly declaring the type of an enum as other than int32 is a bad move in my opinion. Are you trying to save a few bytes on a static type?

Comment: Well, actually i don't know whether it is considered to be a good or bad practice, so thanks.

Comment: After reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746812/best-practices-for-using-and-persisting-enums things seem clear, thank you once again.

Comment: Virtually every enum in the CLR is the default int32. Explicit declaration otherwise, unless the enum is being repurposed in an edge case, for use in an api call requiring a byte for instance, just adds noise. I am measuring best practice from what I have seen, that's all.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a enumeration with the [`[Flags]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) attribute.

```
[Flags]
enum ColorSortQualities
{
    None = 0x0,
    DistinguishColor = 0x1,
    DistinguishNumberOfColors = 0x2,
    DistinguishColorPattern = 0x4
}
```

This will let the caller specify any combination of those, each of which will be implemented as a bit flag.  Note that this will allow 32 options, because int is a 32-bit quantity.

Your condition code would look like:

```
if((searchOptions & ColorSortQualities.DistinguishColor) == ColorSortQualities.DistinguishColor)
```

If that isn't what you mean by "series of Boolean variables", please clarify.