# Parameters substitution not working

Tags: nhibernate

In my config i have this: 
'English (United States)' 1, 'Español (España)' 2

I'm executing a stored procedure that expect an int. I'm getting the 
exception: '...cannot convert nvarchar to int...' . Tha is because the substitution is not working. I never get 'English (United States)'replaced with 1

I'm doing parameter binding this way:

...
string culture = "English (United States)"; 
IQuery query = NHibernateSession.GetNamedQuery(namedQuery) 
    .SetString("IdiomId", culture) 
...

Thnks and hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might have forgotton the equals

> 'English (United States)' 1, 'Español (España)' 2

Try Instead 'English (United States)'= 1, 'Español (España)'= 2

alternativly try looking at this question [how-to-persist-an-enum-using-nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256978/how-to-persist-an-enum-using-nhibernate)